# Adding IOKit from Xcode.app bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, iokit, kif

I am following the [instructions](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) to install KIF from Github, which provide a very detailed step-by-step tour of things to do to make it work. That is, until it reaches this point.

> KIF requires the IOKit.framework. Unfortunately as of Xcode 6.3 you
>   need to manually add IOKit from the Xcode.app bundle. After doing so
>   remove
>   `$(DEVELOPER_DIR)/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`
>   from the Framework Search Path setting (Xcode automatically adds it
>   after manually importing).

What does it mean to *add something from a bundle*? Is there a step-by-step instruction available what I should do to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you have to drag and drop the **IOKit.framework** in Build Phases in the project settings manually because it's not in the picker when you hit the plus button.

You can find the framework here for example:

> Macintosh HD/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

Comment: I have dragged in the framework but when I do `#import <IOKit/IOKit>` I get file not found.

Comment: Did you try #import "IOKit.h" instead? Did you drag and drop and make sure that it is in the build phase section?

Comment: @Michal - Have you found any solution to this ?